# How to model a system which gives input to a system under consideration in a use-case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case

So i have to come-up with a use-case diagram. I have identified the actors and use-cases.

But the question is how should i model some another system(say A) the output of which is kind of input to mine(say B) ?

Can the A be modelled as actor ?

If yes ? Why ?

If not ? How to represent it ?

Please let me know if some more details are required !

Answer (score 1):

You said that you identified the actors!? So A is it one of them? if yes so it must be modeled as actor if it is not so I must be something else...
Actors are object associated to UseCases and that's all.
Now according to what I understood A does not seems to be an Actor so how can you model it. 
It depends of how you want to model the interactions between A and B. If for this you use component diagram A would be a component, if you depict it in a deployment diagram A would be a node or an artifact and in class diagram A would be a class...
So could you detail the interaction between A and B ?